# How to write that in PHP 7.2?

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have this piece of code:

```
private function _resolveCustomEntries($fields)
{
    foreach ($fields as &$value) {
        if (array_key_exists('custom', $value)) {
            if (method_exists($this, $value['custom'])) {
                $value['custom'] = $this->$value['custom'](); //variableInterpolation
            }
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

I ran a PHP 7.2 compatibility check and it complained here with the "variableInterpolation" on the marked line. When I run this code, the PHP log tells me this:

> ERR (3): Notice: Array to string conversion  in
>   /public_html/lib/KiTT/Payment/Widget.php on line 217

Thats the same line where the "variableInterpolation" check failed. So how would I rewrite this code so it works in PHP 7.2?

Thanks!

**Solution:**

```
$value['custom'] = $this->$value['custom']();
```

has to look like this:

```
$value['custom'] = $this->{$value['custom']}();
```

Comment: that should work in php 7.2 - It errors for me in 5.X ?

Comment: Well, the site is running on PHP 7.2  and the compatibility scanner gave me an error for that. Hm...

Comment: have you var_dumped $this, $this->value and $this->value['custom']?

Comment: Its in an Ajax request, so I cant var_dump, can I?

Comment: you can, just console.log the response

Comment: I edited my post, maybe it makes it easier to understand. What do you mean with console.log it? Like in Javascript?

Comment: this error Notice: Array to string conversion means you're trying to convert an array to a string incorrectly - and yeah :) so in your ajax.response section console.log(res) :)

Comment: Fix the order of the evaluations because it seems that `$value` (the array) is stringified first: `$this->{$value['custom']}()` or so should work, you might need an intermediate variable if syntax is wrong `$x = $value['custom']; $this->$x()`

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of order variables are evaled.

With

```
class x {
  public function y() {
    echo 'ok';
  }
}
$x = new x();
$y = array('i' => 'y');
```

Then

```
$x->$y['i']();
```

Fails because PHP first tries to cast the `$y` variable into a string, and get the matching property of `$x` (which btw does not exist), then tries to get the index `'i'` or that unexisting property, and then tries to run it as a callable.

Hence 3 errors:

> Array to string conversion
>
> Undefined property x::$Array
>
> Function name must be a string (nda: the undefined property returns NULL)

Instead, curly brace the variable to set the resolving order:

```
$x->$y['i']();
```

Will work. So use `$this->{$value['custom']}()`

Answer (score 1):

This will throw an array to string conversion in 7.2

```
class bob{


    function foo(){
        return 'bar';
    }

    function getFoo(){

        $value['custom'] = 'foo';

        $value['custom'] = $this->$value['custom']();

        return $value['custom'];
    }


}

$bob = new Bob();

var_dump($bob->getFoo());
```

But it will execute just fine in 5.6.

Then i changed the snippet to this, not calling the method directly casting the array key to function name, but initializing a string (hopefully, there is no type validation in your code) variable with the function name first:

```
class bob{


    function foo(){
        return 'bar';
    }

    function getFoo(){

        $value['custom'] = 'foo';

        $functionName = $value['custom'];

        $value['custom'] = $this->$functionName();

        return $value['custom'];
    }


}

$bob = new Bob();

var_dump($bob->getFoo());
```

This will run just fine in php 7.2

Answer (score -1):

You could try rewriting your code using complex (curly) syntax, you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Your code would look something like this.

```
$value['custom'] = $this->{$value['custom']}();
```

Edit: moved the curly braces to correct positions.

Comment: The idea is here ("use curly brace syntax") but this is an invalid usage of it.